# NativeScript BLE - Update interface while searching device by using nativescript-bluetooth

Tags: angular, typescript, bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript

I am using NativeScript and nativescript-bluetooth plugin to create a BLE searching APP.
I couldn't figure out how to update view while searching device.
Here is my code

app.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NativeScriptModule],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

let ble = require("nativescript-bluetooth");

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    styleUrls: ['app.css'],
    templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
    log: string = "";


    startScanning() {
        ble.startScanning({
            serviceUUIDs: [],
            seconds: 5,
            onDiscovered: (peripheral) => {
                if (peripheral.name == "SWING") {
                    this.stopScanning();
                    this.updateLog(`Device Name: ${peripheral.name}`);
                }
            }
        }).then(() => {
            this.updateLog("scanning completed");
        }, (err) => {
            console.error(`Error on scanning: ${err}`);
        })
    }

    stopScanning() {
        ble.stopScanning().then(() => {
            this.updateLog("Stopped");
        })
    }

    updateLog(message) {
        console.log(message);
        this.log += `\n${message}`;
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<ActionBar title="My App">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-active" id="appButton" text="Search Device" (tap)="startScanning()"></Button>

    <TextView text="{{ log }}" style="height: 100%;background-color: #282a37;color: #fff;" editable="false"></TextView>
</StackLayout>
```

While it scanning, it won't update the log to the view before 5 seconds which finishes the `ble.startScanning`.
I believe it's not related to the BLE plugin. It's more like Javascript Promise and NativeScript issue.

Thank you.

Comment: You aren't using RxJS in this example.

Comment: Yes, @paulpdaniels you are correct. I meant Promise/wait method, not RxJs. I updated the content to remove it. Thank you

Comment: Please also share the `updateLog` function.

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen I did update to include the updateLog function. Thank you

Comment: Is this a NativeScript-Angular app? Please include your entire component, because the advise depends on the rest of your code..

Comment: Yes, it's NativeScript-Angular app. I added all of the code. Thanks for your help @EddyVerbruggen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onDiscovered` callback runs outside Angular's lifecycle, so in order to make Angular aware of the updates (and update the UI consequently) you'll need to give it a little kick.

That's what NgZone is for.

```
// add
constuctor(private zone: NgZone) {}

// within 'onDiscovered', add
this.zone.run(() => {
  this.updateLog(`Device Name: ${peripheral.name}`);
})
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I did know that I need to do things that out of NgZone!! You saved my week!